# Gson: Help me parse gson from server

Tags: android, json, retrofit

The response when call API success is:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "timestamp": "2018/05/16 16:43:21",
        "status": "OK"
    },
    "body": {....}
```

But response when call same API above in error case is:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "timestamp": "2018/08/16 15:52:45",
        "status": "VALIDATION_ERROR"
    },
    "body": [
        {
            "errorCode": "aaa",
            "errorMessage": "ERROR1",
            "property": "AAA",
            "args": "aa"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see the response body is diffrence, one is Json array, one is json object, how can I parse if I use retrofit ?

Comment: the api will return object as well as array for the `body` field? sounds weird

Comment: I want when response success, I can parse to model success and if response error, I can parse to model error

Comment: then you may need a TypeAdapter

Comment: TypeAdapter , what is this ?

Comment: That's bad API design. If you can (e.g. if it's in house), try to make the API guys consolidate it. Otherwise, you'll need to make your own TypeAdapter.

Comment: thx for ur answer, actually the API from the other side, I cant change it, its bad, but I need to parse it, so the last solution is get response by string and parse 2 time, the 1st time is check response ok or not, the 2nd is parse body :(

Answer (score 0):

your model class should be RootObject like this

```
public class RootObject
{
private Meta meta;

public Meta getMeta() { return this.meta; }

public void setMeta(Meta meta) { this.meta = meta; }

private ArrayList<Body> body;

public ArrayList<Body> getBody() { return this.body; }

public void setBody(ArrayList<Body> body) { this.body = body; }
}
```

---

```
public class Meta
{
private String timestamp;

public String getTimestamp() { return this.timestamp; }

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) { this.timestamp = timestamp; }

private String status;

public String getStatus() { return this.status; }

public void setStatus(String status) { this.status = status; }
}
```

---

```
public class Body
{
private String errorCode;

public String getErrorCode() { return this.errorCode; }

public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) { this.errorCode = errorCode; }

private String errorMessage;

public String getErrorMessage() { return this.errorMessage; }

public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) { this.errorMessage = errorMessage; }

private String property;

public String getProperty() { return this.property; }

public void setProperty(String property) { this.property = property; }

private String args;

public String getArgs() { return this.args; }

public void setArgs(String args) { this.args = args; }
}
```

Comment: but the body when response success is a object, when error is array, your model only parse done when response  error but can't apply when response  success

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Ridcully, this is a bad API design. Since you cannot modify the API, the workaround would be using inheritance and adding a custom `typeAdapter` to the Gson instance.

Notice that `SuccessResponse` and `FailureResponse` "is-a" `Response`. When you use typeAdapter for `Response` class, the custom deserializer will determine whether the object should be deserialized into `SuccessResponse` class or `FailureResponse` class based on the value of `Response.meta.status`.

**Response Parent Class**

```
public class Response{
     private Meta meta;

     public Meta getMeta(){ return meta; }
     public void setMeta(Meta meta){ this.meta = meta; }

}
```

**Success Response Child Class**

```
public class SuccessResponse extends Response{
     private SuccessContent body;

     public SuccessContent getSuccessContent() { return body; }
     public void setSuccessContent(SuccessContent content) { this.body = content }
 }
```

**Failure Response Child Class**

```
public class FailureResponse extends Response{
     private List<FailureContent> body;

     public List<FailureContent> getBody() { return body; }
     public void setObjList(List<FailureContent> content) { this.body= content; }
}
```

**Success Content Class**

```
public class SucessContent{
     //Model class of the success body
}
```

**Failure Content Class**

```
public class FailureContent{
     private String errorCode;
     private String errorMessage;
     private String property;
     private String args;

     public String getErrorCode() { return errorCode; }
     public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) { this.errorCode = errorCode; }

     public String getErrorMessage() { return errorMessage; }
     public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) { this.errorMessage = errorMessage;}

     public String getProperty() { return property; }
     public void setProperty(String property) { this.property = property; }

     public String getArgs() { return args; }
     public void setArgs(String args) { this.args = args; }

}
```

**Meta Class**

```
public class Meta{
     private String timestamp;
     private String status;

     public String getTimestamp() { return this.timestamp; }
     public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) { this.timestamp = timestamp; }

     public String getStatus() { return this.status; }
     public void setStatus(String status) { this.status = status; }
}
```

**Custom type adapter of Gson for deserialize Response class**

```
public class ResponseBodyAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Response> {
      @Override
      public Response deserialize (JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDerializationContext context) throws JsonParseException{
              JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();
              JsonObject metaObj = obj.getAsJsonObject("meta");
              String status = metaObj.get("status").getAsString();
              if(status.equals("OK")){
                 return context.deserialize(json, SuccessResponse.class);
              }else if(status.equals("VALIDATION_ERROR")){
                 return context.deserialize(json, FailureResponse.class);
              }
              return null;
        } 
 }
```

**Register the type adapter to gson and for retrofit**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Response.class, new ResponseBodyAdapter ())
                .create();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                       .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                      .build();
```